# Replace part of an array with the average of its neighbors

Tags: arrays, matlab, average

I created this variable in the workspace:

```
z=

0.000894000000000000

-0.000929000000000000

0.00101500000000000

0.000747000000000000

0.00103900000000000

0.000888000000000000

0.000828000000000000

0.000737000000000000

0.000858000000000000

-0.000723000000000000

0.000874000000000000
```

I would like to write code that will replace the negative ones with the average of the numbers found directly above and below this number.

Comment: How do you handle the case where there are multiple negatives in consecutive sequence?

Comment: Also, what happens if the first element and/or last element is negative?

Comment: So what's the deal?  Did any of us answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

Not the most efficient approach, but...

```
av = conv(z, [.5 0 .5], 'same');  %// compute average for all elements
ind = z<0;                        %// determine which are negative
z(ind) = av(ind);                 %// replace those only
```

Comment: Still a valid approach nonetheless :)

Answer (score 3):

You can approach this in a linear interpolation viewpoint.  Assuming that there are no consecutive negative numbers in `z`, you can do this with [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html):

```
%// Define your data
z= [...
0.000894000000000000
-0.000929000000000000
0.00101500000000000
0.000747000000000000
0.00103900000000000
0.000888000000000000
0.000828000000000000
0.000737000000000000
0.000858000000000000
-0.000723000000000000
0.000874000000000000];

keys = (1 : numel(z)).';
out = interp1(keys(z >= 0), z(z >= 0), keys, 'linear', 'extrap');
```

This also handles the case where there are negative values at the beginning and at the end, and the `extrap` flag simply extrapolates.  I'm not sure if this is what you intended if there are values at the beginning and end that are negative, but I'll leave that for you to figure out.

Nevertheless, the beauty behind this approach is that we provide control points that are delineated from 1 up to as many points in `z` that we have.  These are the `x` points.  The output `y` points are the values in `z`.  However, we remove those control points that are negative - the same is done for `z`.

Next, we specify the full spectrum of key points from 1 up to as many elements in `z` to achieve the final output.  Using linear interpolation in this case effectively finds the average between the two points that are separated by a negative.

However, should there be consecutive negative numbers, then what will happen is that we take a look at the value that was positive before the chain of negative values began and look at the value that was positive after the chain, and in between the run of consecutive numbers, the values are smoothly interpolated.  I'm not sure if this is what you want, so I'll leave that here for you to figure out.

This is the output we get:

```
>> format long g;
>> out

out =

              0.000894
             0.0009545
              0.001015
              0.000747
              0.001039
              0.000888
              0.000828
              0.000737
              0.000858
              0.000866
              0.000874
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html), but under the following assumptions:

This code works with the following assumptions:

1. `z` does not have a negative number at the start and at the end
2. There are no consecutive negative numbers in `z`.

Therefore:

```
%// Find negative values in z
ind = find(z < 0);

%// Replace each negative value with the
%// average of the values above and below each negative
z(ind) = (z(ind-1) + z(ind+1)) / 2;
```

The above code mutates `z` so that the negative values are replaced by the neighbouring average.  We again get:

```
>> format long g;
>> z

z =

              0.000894
             0.0009545
              0.001015
              0.000747
              0.001039
              0.000888
              0.000828
              0.000737
              0.000858
              0.000866
              0.000874
```

Comment: Also, one might want to specify the extrapolation argument, to account for the case when end elements are negative (I suggest `'nearest'` extrapolation algorithm here)

Comment: Probably the best approach!

Comment: @BenVoigt - Correct.  Let me change my post.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I assumed that the first and last elements aren't negative, although you have a point with the extrapolation.

Comment: Alternate approach with `interp1` is nice :) +1

Comment: `interp1` method is good, you should move it to the top of your answer rather?

Comment: @Dan - Done.  Thank you for your input.  I've modified it based on your suggestion.  I also added in the `extrap` flag to account for negative values at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for index = 1 : length( z )
    if ( z( index ) < 0 ) // FIXED
        above = max( index, 1 );
        below = min( index, length( z ) );
        z( index ) = mean( z( above ), z( below ) ); // FIXED
    end
end
```

but this is not fully correct. What should happen in the following cases:

- As in the question of @Ĭnfernal Seraphím when the neighbours are also negativ.
- If there the first and last items are negativ ?

Comment: I mistyped it. I'll fix it.

Comment: One more comment.  `above` and `below` actually don't do anything.  It's basically just equal to `index`.  Did you mean for `above` to be `above = max(index - 1, 1);` and `below` to be `below = min(index + 1, length(z));`??